# What's wrong with this SQL Create Table Statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, create-table

This SQL query is generated by SQL Server Managment Studio and it throws me an error:

```
USE [database_name]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[UserAddress]    Script Date: 02/17/2010 11:21:02 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserAddress]
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [UserID] [int] NULL,
    [AddressName] [nvarchar](25) NULL,
    [Fname] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [LName] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [City] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [Street] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    [StreetNum] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
    [FloorNum] [int] NULL,
    [AptNum] [int] NULL,
    [ZipCode] [int] NULL,
    [Phone] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [Phone_Prefix] [int] NULL,
    [CellPhone] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [CellPhone_Prefix] [int] NULL,
    [Fax] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [Fax_Prefix] [int] NULL,
    [Primary] [bit] NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_UserAddress] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [ID] ASC
    )
    WITH
    (
        PAD_INDEX  = OFF,
        STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF,
        IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,
        ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON,
        ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
```

The error is: `Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Line 27 Line 27: Incorrect syntax near '('.` pointing at `[CellPhone_Prefix] [int] NULL,` but this line looks fine to me.
What could be wrong?
EDIT:
I just commented out the

```
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Users] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC,
    [ClientStoreID] ASC,
    [Uname] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

and now it works, why?
EDIT 2:
I narrowed it down to:

```
WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Works fine for me on SQL Server 2005. What version are you using?

Comment: I just copy-pasted your code in my  studio and it created the table without any problems ..

Comment: If you are running the sql using SSMS, make sure you don't have just part of the query highlighted when running it - if you do, it will only execute the highlighted part.

Comment: @adrianbanks: not doing that.

Comment: i wonder why people use queries to create tables rather than easily using some client software.

Comment: @Sarfraz: Because it's a big table and I can't remember everything

Comment: Your query fails for me with the same error you are getting. My SQL server is 2000, but I'm using SSMS 2005 to access it.

Comment: Just as an FYI, the line # references starts at the beginning of the create table command, not the script.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this is down to SQL server database version.

I tried your query using SSMS 2005 against a SQL server 2000 database and it fails with the same error you describes.

When I connected to a SQL server 2005 server the query executes perfectly.

Have you definitely checked your server version, and not just your SSMS version.

According to the [SQL Server 2000](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258255%28SQL.80%29.aspx) syntax, the WITH part only allows FillFactor to be set, and nothing else:

```
< table_constraint > ::= [ CONSTRAINT constraint_name ]
{ [ { PRIMARY KEY | UNIQUE }
    [ CLUSTERED | NONCLUSTERED ]
    { ( column [ ASC | DESC ] [ ,...n ] ) }
    [ WITH FILLFACTOR = fillfactor ]
    [ ON { filegroup | DEFAULT } ]
]
```

This differs from the [SQL Server 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx)/[2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979%28SQL.90%29.aspx) syntax which allows multiple options within brackets:

```
< table_constraint > ::= [ CONSTRAINT constraint_name ] 
{  { PRIMARY KEY | UNIQUE } 
    [ CLUSTERED | NONCLUSTERED ] 
    (column [ ASC | DESC ] [ ,...n ] ) 
    [ WITH FILLFACTOR = fillfactor | WITH ( <index_option> [ , ...n ] ) ]
    [ ON { partition_scheme_name (partition_column_name) | filegroup | "default" } ] 
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: Thanks, won't it cause me any trouble later on?

Comment: @the_drow: Depends what you are doing. The SQL server 2008 link covers what all the options mean, (you just have to search in the page). Those options are obviously not supported in sql server 2000, so you need to read them and check if you are relying on any of their behaviour in your app.