# SQL Server : query error

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2000

I try creating this table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[WEBENGINE_ACTIVE_SESSIONS]
(
    [session_user_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [session_id] [varchar](50) COLLATE Chinese_PRC_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [session_time] [varchar](50) COLLATE Chinese_PRC_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [session_ip] [varchar](25) COLLATE Chinese_PRC_CI_AS NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_WEBENGINE_ACTIVE_SESSIONS] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    ([session_user_id] ASC)WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

and I get error:

> [Err] 42000 - [SQL Server]Line 10: Incorrect syntax near '('.

Comment: Looks like it's due to database compatibility issue. Check here http://stackoverflow.com/q/2279536/2993606

Comment: You have to leave `WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF)` out

Comment: Thanks, you are right. This is a MS SQL Server 2000 limits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to leave WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) in SQL Server 2000.

Make sure you start with a NEW QUERY window.

Comment: I use MS SQL Server 2000, query analyzer generate error:Server: Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
Line 9: Incorrect syntax near '('. I try using navicat, connect to sql server successfuly and in new query get same error.